# Subsetting a list in a dataframe column with another list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
    id  event_explain
1   80  list("Minutes played", 0, 0)
2   81  list("Minutes played", 0, 0)
3   82  list("Bonus", 2, 2, "Clean sheets", 1, 4, "Minutes played", 90, 2)
```

I'm trying to pull out the number after "Minutes Played", so in this example, I would end up with something like 0,0,90.

I have created some kind of index list to identify the element "Minutes Played"

```
    list(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

and was thinking that perhaps I could permute (somehow) the T/F in each list element to then pull out the number following the element.

The problem is, I can't even work out how to subset the dataframe column to pull out an element of a list, let alone permute the Trues and Falses!

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to consider restructuring your data.frame to avoid having a column of lists.

Comment: Are you garanteed to have one and only one "Minutes played" by row, followed by a numeric? If not, what would you like to do?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution.

First, some sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  id = c(80, 81, 82), event = I(
    list(list("Minutes played", 0, 0),
         list("Minutes played", 0, 0), 
         list("Bonus", 2, 2, "Clean sheets", 1, 4, "Minutes played", 90, 2))))
```

Use `grep` to identify the string "Minutes played". That will return the numeric position. You want the value just after that, so we add 1 to the output of `grep` to get the numbers you're looking for.

```
unlist(sapply(mydf$event, function(x) x[grep("Minutes played", x)+1]))
# [1]  0  0 90
```

Or, alternatively, with `match`:

```
unlist(sapply(mydf$event, function(x) x[match("Minutes played", x)+1]))
# [1]  0  0 90
```

---

Alternatively, since you say you have already created an index list, you can just use the following:

```
## Your index list
Index <- list(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
              c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
              c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

## Extracting what you want
unlist(mydf$event)[which(unlist(Index))+1]
# [1] "0"  "0"  "90"
```

Comment: @flodel, can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Why I prefer `match` to `grep`? a) it will better handle the possibility that there is no match because `match` still returns a vector of length 1, here `NA`. b) It will match the string exactly. c) I think it will be faster (I guess `==` is faster than `grep`, also I think `match` stops as soon as it finds one match.)

Answer (score 0):

```
## borrow the man above's data
mydf <- data.frame(
  id = c(80, 81, 82), event = I(
    list(list("Minutes played", 0, 0),
         list("Minutes played", 0, 0), 
         list("Bonus", 2, 2, "Clean sheets", 1, 4, "Minutes played", 90, 2))))
result<-c()
for (i in 1:3) {
    if("Minutes played" %in% mydf$event[[i]]) {
        result<-c(result,mydf$event[[i]][which("Minutes played" == mydf$event[[i]])+1] )
    }
}
```